# javascript - passing a string to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, innerhtml

This onmouseover 'lookdown' function works but the onmouseout 'lookup' function does not:

```
function lookdown(harvid) { harvid.innerHTML="See details below"; }
function lookup(harvid,crop) {harvid.innerHTML=crop;}

<td id="harv1244" onmouseover="lookdown(harv1244)"
onmouseout="lookup(harv1244,apples)">dummy</td>
```

This onmouseout function works (although, of course, it prints 'crop' and I want to pass in a string as I am trying to do above):

```
function lookup(harvid) {harvid.innerHTML="crop";}

<td id="harv1244" onmouseover="lookdown(harv1244)"
onmouseout="lookup(harv1244)">dummy</td>
```

Comment: what is apples here ?

Comment: Avoid this, really. You're relying on the browser creating global variables for your ids, and inline events are a source of errors. Add your events _in JavaScript_, querying your elements from the DOM and then using `addEventListener`.

Comment: `apples` isn't a string, but a variable. Does it hold a string value?

Comment: Mritunjay, apples is the word that I am passing to the lookup() function that I want inserted using innerHTML.

Comment: elclans, I don't know what any of that means.

Comment: Bergi, apples is a string produced by php, but the resulting html code is exactly as you see. I have tried putting 'apples' in quotes in the html, and in the javascript function and in all combinations that I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You are passing undeclared variables into your functions. `apples` and `harvid` are variables, not strings, and therefore undefined.  You need to put those values in quotes to make them strings
- `harvid` needs to either be a string or a node element.  But you are not passing in either.  Assuming you want it to be a string, you then need to find the DOM element using `getElementById`.

Here is a working solution:

Javascript:

```
function lookdown(harvid) { 
    document.getElementById(harvid).innerHTML="See details below"; 
}

function lookup(harvid,crop) {
    document.getElementById(harvid).innerHTML=crop;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="harv1244" onmouseover="lookdown('harv1244')"
onmouseout="lookup('harv1244','apples')">
    dummy
</div>
```

And here the associated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pQM37/

EDIT:

To make this code a little cleaner, you could pass the element itself into the function, instead of the `id`, like this:

Javascript:

```
function lookdown(ele) { 
    ele.innerHTML="See details below"; 
}

function lookup(ele,crop) {
    ele.innerHTML=crop;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="harv1244" onmouseover="lookdown(this)"
onmouseout="lookup(this,'apples')">
    dummy
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pQM37/1/

Comment: That's perfect, Steve. Clear, two solutions, and a working example. Could not be better. Thanks.